# Why is resizing not working correctly on this element in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Anyone have a clue why this dropdown isn't behaving as expected? It's working on normal resizes as shown first in the gif, but not in chromes responsiveness debug thing. It seems the window width is maybe not being updated correctly? I know `useEffect` applies after the rendering cycle, so I tried using `useLayoutEffect` but there is no change in behaviour
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q9Mq.jpg

```js
function Navigation() {
  const [isShown, setShown] = useState(false);
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowResize = () => {
      setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
    };
  });


  const showValue = {
    position: "absolute",
    left: `${windowWidth - 400}px`,
    top: "56px"
  };

  const hideValue = {
    position: "absolute",
    left: `${windowWidth - 400}px`,
    top: "56px",
    visibility: "hidden",
    transitionProperty: "visibility",
    transitionDelay: "0.5s"
  };

  function signInDropDown(style) {
    return (
      <Container className={styles.user_drop_down} style={style}>
        {style.left}
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <NavDropdown.Item>Sign in</NavDropdown.Item>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
           <NavDropdown.Item>A button</NavDropdown.Item>
        </Row>
        <Row>
         <NavDropdown.Item>Another Button</NavDropdown.Item>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  return (
      <Nav.Link onMouseOver={() => setShown(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setShown(false)}>
              <BiUser  color="white" size="1.5rem" className={styles.cart_icon}></BiUser>
              {isShown ? 
              signInDropDown(showValue) : signInDropDown(hideValue)}
      </Nav.Link>
  );
}
```

```css
.user_drop_down {
    background-color:coral;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

I also added a button to trigger useEffect without changing the windowWidth again to see if it would fix on the next render pass, which it didn't, so I'm sure it's nothing to do with my use of `useEffect`

edit:
still no clue on this but it only occurs when resizing through responsive mode, if the window size is changed normally it doesn't happen

Comment: You should add a empty [dependency array](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect?ref=javascript-guides#examples-dependencies) to the `useEffect`

Comment: Please please please don't ... this is a job for CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the account hover on amazon https://www.amazon.co.uk/ and it seems the positioning can only be achieved via JS, which is what they do as well

Comment: Have you got a meta tag of this form in your head element? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: @AHaworth I do, it was included by create-react-app ```   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />```